# Is it possible to reuse a Google reCaptcha token?

Tags: javascript, security, recaptcha

Basically my client wants me to use a Google reCaptcha response token as part of the user session.

The idea being that if the client asks for some data from the back end (an image for instance), I can take the reCaptcha reponse token that I'm saving as a session variable or possibly a cookie and resubmit it to Google https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify API again to see if it is still valid.

Is this possible? And does this make sense to do.

Basically they are trying to use reCaptcha to stop bots from scraping their files.

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: if it is proved once, why ask it again?

Comment: Well, i think the idea is that some how we can reuse the key somehow, but I'm not sure how to authenticate that it's valid.

Basically my client wants assurance that the people who are asking for the data are real users and doesn't want to have to keep asking for them to authenticate.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well you ask it once and store it in session that you know it is them... That is how basic authentication works. You do not log into stack overflow every time you want to post.

Comment: Hmm, i agree. I think the client doesn't understand. But i guess his thinking is that we can use the key over and over again. Let me put it another way. How do I verify that the session key is still valid after some time has passed?

Comment: If you use the invisibleCaptcha, reCAPTCHA will automatically decide if it needs or not to display the prompt to confirm they are humans.  In most cases your users will have nothing to do.  The invisible captcha will return you a token for every request which you can validate server side.

Answer (score 7):

No replay attacks using the same tokens are prohibited by ReCaptcha.

> Token Restrictions
>
> Each reCAPTCHA user response token is valid for two minutes, and can only be verified once to prevent replay attacks. If you need a new token, you can re-run the reCAPTCHA verification.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify